# JUnit wont quit Loop configured in JMeter

Tags: junit, while-loop, jmeter

I wrote a Jmeter Test that contains a While-Controller. The Test looks somewhat like this:

```
> Testlan
>> VARS
>> Thread
>>> HTTP Request
>>> Transaction Controller
>>>> User Parameters
>>>> HTTP Request
>> Result Tree
>> Test Fragment
>>> Transaction Controller
>>>> Init Loop Beanshell
>>>> Loop with Condition
>>>>> BeanShell Assertion
```

In "Init Loop Beanshell" I do this: `vars.put("MyVar","okay");`
So my While-Condition looks kinda like this: `${__javaScript("${MyVar}"!="stop")}`
In my Assertion, there is a point where I do this: `vars.put("MyVar", "stop");`

The strange thing is, that in JMeter it works just fine and the loop is quit when the condition is false. In JUnit its just an endless loop. I already checked the vars in the JUnit log and MyVar is "stop" but it just doesn't quit the loop.
The log says: `Condition value: false`

I already wasted to much hours on figuring out why this wont work. I just want that the test quits the loop when i call it from JUnit as it is when i call it from JMeter.

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for the fast reply. Sadly, it doesn't work. If I change javaScript to groovy, even in the JMeter GUI the WhileLoop won't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone cares, i solved it with a workaround.
All those ${__javaScript/groovy/...(CONDITION)} did not work and i still don't know why.

But what worked in both jMeter and jUnit was to set the While-Condition on `${MyVar}`, initialize it with `vars.put("MyVar","true");` and "clean" it on the Assertion with `vars.put("MyVar", "false");`

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not correct, you should change this line:

```
${__javaScript(${"MyVar"}!="stop")}
```

to this one:

```
${__javaScript("${MyVar}"!="stop")}
```

Also from performance perspective it's better to use [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function

With regards to Beanshell - using it is a some form of performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error. I already fixed that but forgot to correct it in the question. I tried both jexl3 and groovy but neither works. I tried also
${__jexl3(vars.get("MyVar")!=null)} and in my Assertion vars.remove("MyVar") which works again in JMeter but not in JUnit

Comment: What do you mean by "JUnit"?

Comment: In an Java environment, i initialize the call of JMeter-Tests by using JUnit functions, e.g. to execute tests there is jmeter.run();

Comment: Several people reported this problem in comments to the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) post, double check that you have [ApacheJMeter_functions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions) in your project classpath